# How to call same method with different Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html controls of two sets with different ids in my page, when I click `a` tag I want to call `DoSomething` method.

```
<div>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething();">
   <span id="spnValue" >Value1</span>
</div>

<div>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething();">
   <span id="spnValue1">Value2</span>
</div>

function DoSomething() {
   var htmlVal = "";
   skuList  = $("span[id*='spnValue']").html();
}
```

But whichever one I click it gives the `Value1` in htmlVal. How can I distinguish and retrieve the value of method called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass clicked element object to method:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething(this);">
<span id="spnValue1">Value2</span>
</div>
```

and then use it for traversing to child span element:

```
function DoSomething(obj) {
  var htmlVal = "";
  skuList  = $(obj).find('span').html();
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qh3deb5/)**

Comment: What if they are all in one div abd `a` tag closed before span. Eg. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/7qh3deb5/1/

Comment: What if span is in multiples divs, `next` is giving undefined

Comment: @hachitti: off course.traversing will break. share that markup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90322/discussion-between-ha-chitti-and-milind-anantwar).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething(this);">
      <span id="spnValue1">Value2</span>
</div>

function DoSomething(obj) {
    var htmlVal = "";
    skuList  = $(obj).parent().find('span').html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current element in the function using that you can locate the span element which is a children on the a tag

```
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething(this);">
     <span id="spnValue" >Value1</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomething(this);">
     <span id="spnValue1">Value2</span>
  </a>
</div>

function DoSomething(node) {
   var htmlVal = "";
   skuList  = $(node).find('span').html();//for children
   //skuList  = $(node).next('span').html();//for siblings
}
```